# MahApps - SimpleChildWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to setup a [SimpleChildWindow](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow) from the MahApps package

Unfortunately I cound not understand the sample and have a couple of questions:

1. It says:

> Directly in XAML

- where should I put that?

In the parent's window or is this the separate window?

2. `await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new CoolChildWindow() { IsModal = false });`

   - where do we get that `CoolChildWindow()`?

Would be grateful for any help or an extended code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Directly in XAML" means: put your child windows inside your root grid.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow.Demo.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      xmlns:simpleChildWindow="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow;assembly=MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow"
                      Title="MahApps.Metro Simple ChildWindow Demo"
                      GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">

        <Grid>
            <!-- main content here -->
        </Grid>

        <simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow x:Name="child01"
                                       CloseByEscape="False"
                                       Closing="Child01_OnClosing"
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                       Padding="15"
                                       ChildWindowImage="Error"
                                       Title="TestChild 1">
            <Grid>
                <!-- child content here -->
            </Grid>
        </simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow>

        <simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow x:Name="child02"
                                       ChildWindowWidth="400"
                                       ChildWindowHeight="300"
                                       EnableDropShadow="False"
                                       Title="TestChild 2">
            <Grid>
                <!-- child content here -->
            </Grid>
        </simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow>

    </Grid>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

If you prefer code behind usage, then you can create a custom ChildWindow like `CustomChildWindow` and create and call it like this

```
private async void OpenCustomChildWindow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new CustomChildWindow() { IsModal = false }, RootGrid);
    // or
    //await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new CustomChildWindow() { IsModal = false }, OverlayFillBehavior.WindowContent);
    // or
    //await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(new CustomChildWindow() { IsModal = true }, OverlayFillBehavior.FullWindow);
}
```

You can find this also at the main demo on GitHub.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your example! :)